# How to connect to a redshift database with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, amazon-redshift, cypress

I am having issues trying to connect to a redshift database on Cypress, I've followed the instructions from the official [cypress-sql-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-sql-server) webpage, please see my configurations files below

--> **cypress.json**

```
"db": {
    "userName": "MY_USERNAME",
    "password": "MY_PASSWORD",
    "server": "MY_SERVER",
    "options": {
        "database": "MY_DATABASE",
        "encrypt": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true,
    }
}
```

--> **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin": "^2.23.0",
    "cypress": "^9.2.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.3.0",
    "cypress-sql-server": "^1.0.0"
}
```

--> **cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const dbConfig = require('../../cypress.json');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
    // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

    /** SQL Server configuration */
    tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbConfig.db);
    on('task', tasks);

    return config;
}
```

--> **cypress/integration/test_spec.js**

```
describe("My First Test", () => {
  it("Does not do much!", () => {
    cy.sqlServer('SELECT *');
  });
});
```

I have two behaviors

The first one is when I specify the database port on the cypress.json like this:

```
"db": {
    "userName": "MY_USERNAME",
    "password": "MY_PASSWORD",
    "server": "MY_SERVER",
    "options": {
        "database": "MY_DATABASE",
        "encrypt": true,
        "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true,
        "port": 5439
    }
}
```

I got a socket hang up error, which is the following

> My First Test
>
> The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your
> tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file
> (`../cypress/plugins/index.js`)
>
> ConnectionError: Connection lost - socket hang up
> at ConnectionError (../node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError (../node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1012:26)
> at Connection.socketEnd (../node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1031:12)
> at Socket. (../node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:890:14)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:387:35)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

The second behavior is when I no specify the port on the cypress.json file, Cypress is taking the port "1433" (which is not the desired) it fail to connect:

> 1. My First Test
>    Does not do much!:
>    CypressError: `cy.task('sqlServer:execute')` failed with the following error:
>
> > Failed to connect to MY_SERVER:1433 in 15000ms